# How to check request.user against an unrelated model in Django

Tags: django, request, m2m

My question is a little difficult to explain but I'll try my best. Please ask if anything needs to be clarified.

I have three models, Exercise, Area, and Workout:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Area(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    exercise = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise, blank=True)

class Workout(models.Model):
    weight = models.DecimalField(default=0.0)
    reps = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The user will complete a form that adds objects to Area. They can then go into that object and complete a new form that adds objects to Exercise, which are also attached to the specific area through M2M. In order to display only the exercises that this particular user has created, I have an if statement in the exercise template:

```
{% if area.user.user == request.user %}`
    {{ exercise.name }}
{% endif %}
```

I want the user to now be able to go into the Exercise object and complete a form that adds to Workout. I can achieve this but my question is how can I make sure only the logged in users workouts are displayed? `area.user.user` has no affect since Area is unrelated to this template and I cannot add a user to the Exercise model.

**Edit**

```
class WorkoutView(DetailView):
    model = Exercise
    template_name = 'tracker/workouts.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WorkoutView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['profile'] = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        context['form'] = form
        return context


from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your view please.

Comment: Hi @sgt_pepper85! Usually you would do this in your view and not in the template. Add a ```login_required```-decorator or Mixin to your view so only logged in users can access it. In the view filter your data with the user of the request, ```request.user```. I see that you refer in your ```Area``` not the djangos user model but to a model called ```Profile```, can you give us information about that too, please?

Comment: Thanks Lewis and @Yves Hary for responding. I have edited my question to show the view which displays the workouts, and also a snippet of my Profile model linking user to the auth user model as requested

Comment: Please tell me if I get you right: You want to display all Workout-Objects which belong to the currently logged in user?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 2):

Based on your information I think this solution could be appropriate. First, if you want to display multiple objects, django provides the `ListView` which is more appropriate to your needs. Everything can stay as it is besides your view.

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class WorkoutView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView): 
# This mixin prevents access from not logged in users
   template_name = 'tracker/workouts.html'
   queryset = Workout.objects.all()

   def get_queryset(self):
      # Here we can modify the initial queryset and
      # filter it against the logged in user.
      # Beware that this is not tested and can have bugs.
      # Getting all areas related to the profile of the user
      qs_area = Area.objects.filter(user__user=self.request.user)
      # Getting all exercises related to these areas
      qs_exercises = Exercise.objects.filter(area__in=qs_area)
      # Getting all workouts related to these exercises
      # Django will use subqueries to do this
      self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(exercise__in=qs_exercises)

      return super().get_queryset()
```

You can access the retrieved data in your template with:

```
{% for element in object_list %}
{{ element }}
{% endfor %}
```

To be honest, it is really difficult to get the workouts of a user. Perhaps you should spend some extra hours to improve your database model.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me here. I realise this one is a real pain. I spent the whole day altering my models yesterday and could not come up with a better way that worked. I ran your code just now and received the AttributeError `type object 'Exercise' has no attribute 'filter'`

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, it should be ```Exercise.objects.filter(...)```. I edited the snippet. A good idea would be to draw your current situation of the reality on a sheet of paper and think how you can model this in a database. It seems to me that you are not clear with your usecase.

Comment: Ah yes. But now I am only seeing an empty page

Comment: So, from now on you have to figure it out on your own :-) use your debugger and look if the currently logged in user has workouts matching at all ...?

Comment: Haha that's fair. I'll play with it from here. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: Just realised what this code does. My mistake, I told you I want to display all the users workouts. I was already able to do that. What I want is to find a way so that a logged in user can only see their own workouts and others can't. I knew this was a hard one to describe

Comment: So I have a page that displays a form that users can complete to enter a workout. The workout will then be displayed underneath the form. The users arrive at this page via the id of the exercise. What I want is if someone arrives at the workout page of an exercise they didn't create, that the information will be hidden from that user

Comment: Ok, so, when the user is logged in, he sees only the data which belongs to himself? That would mean, if a not logged in user enters the page, he sees nothing. Is that what you want?

Comment: Almost but I also want to prevent logged in users accessing data they didn't create

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224847/discussion-between-yves-hary-and-sgt-pepper85).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a user field with a foreign key to Profile in my Workout model and then instantiate the view. Thanks to @Yves Hary for figuring this out